# What is the best way to upload a temporary & sensitive file and then delete it when done

Tags: uploads, security, transient

What is the best way to upload a temporary & sensitive file and then delete it when done.

I'm writing a plugin (eventually for multisite) that allows users with a certain role to upload a .csv file that is processed and imported into the db. During processing, the user needs to click 'next' a few times because there are important reality-checks going on - about 5 steps. The csv files contains sensitive information and once processed, I want to ensure that no other user could possible read the file, so I want it safely deleted.

All of the resources I've seen are around uploading media files that are sort of meant to stick around and be shared - so those are not helpful.

Comment: Store it above the web root or alternately, process it and store that info in the db temporarily and then just delete it.

Comment: sounds reasonable - so I guess there isn't any wordpress sanctioned method?  Bummer

Comment: The one time I did it I wrote a custom streaming script and stored *all* media outside the web root and then performed authentication in that script depending on what was requested.  But that's a nuclear option for sites that need to lock down content and has an obvious performance cost.  But, you can just modify a couple options in WordPress to change where media is uploaded to and then its content path to the streaming script, so it was the "WordPress" way I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and finally wrote some code

```
<?php
/**
 * @author  HeyMehedi
 * @since   1.0
 * @version 1.0
 */

 namespace HeyMehedi;

 use WP_Error;

 class Temporary_File_Manager {

    protected static $instance = null;
    public $upload_type;
    public $allowed_extensions;
    public $size_limit;
    public $project_name;

    public $uploaded_files;
    public $seconds;
    public $max;
    public $dir_name;

    public $rand;

    public function __construct( $args = array() ) {
        $this->prepare_property( $args );
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'init_uploads' ) );
        add_action( 'template_redirect', array( $this, 'cleanup_upload_files' ), 20, 0 );
    }

    public static function instance() {
        if ( null == self::$instance ) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    private function prepare_property( $args, $project_name = 'project_name' ) {

        $this->default = array(
            'allowed_extensions'              => array( 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'JPG', 'JPEG', 'PNG', 'BMP' ),
            'size_limit'                      => 10485760,
            'project_name'                    => $project_name,
            'uploaded_files'                  => 'tmp',
            'dir_name'                        => 'tmp',
            'remove_file_if_older_than_secs'  => 60,
            'max_items_remove_when_func_call' => 100,
        );

        $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $this->default );
        $args = apply_filters( "{$project_name}_args", $args );

        $this->allowed_extensions = $args['allowed_extensions'];
        $this->size_limit         = $args['size_limit'];
        $this->project_name       = $args['project_name'];
        $this->uploaded_files     = $args['uploaded_files'];
        $this->dir_name           = $args['dir_name'];
        $this->seconds            = $args['remove_file_if_older_than_secs'];
        $this->max                = $args['max_items_remove_when_func_call'];
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the temporary directory for uploaded files.
     */
    public function init_uploads() {
        $dir = $this->get_upload_dir();

        if ( is_dir( $dir ) and is_writable( $dir ) ) {
            $htaccess_file = path_join( $dir, '.htaccess' );

            if ( ! file_exists( $htaccess_file )
                and $handle = @fopen( $htaccess_file, 'w' ) ) {
                fwrite( $handle, "Deny from all\n" );
                fclose( $handle );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Uploaded files and moves them to the temporary directory.
     *
     * @param should be $_FILES, Default param `$_FILES`.
     * @return array|WP_Error file path or file urls, or WP_Error if validation fails.
     */
    public function upload_files( $return_url = false ) {
        $this->uploaded_files = array();
        foreach ( $_FILES as $key => $file ) {
            $file_path = $this->upload_single_file( $file, $return_url );
            if ( $file_path ) {
                $this->uploaded_files[] = $file_path;
            }
        }

        return $this->uploaded_files;
    }

    /**
     * Validates uploaded file and move to the temporary directory.
     *
     * @param array $file an item of `$_FILES`.
     * @return string|WP_Error file path | file url, or WP_Error if validation fails.
     */
    public function upload_single_file( $file, $return_url = false ) {

        // Move uploaded file to tmp dir
        $dir      = $this->get_upload_dir();
        $rand_dir = $this->maybe_add_random_dir( $dir );
        $tmp_name = isset( $file['tmp_name'] ) ? $file['tmp_name'] : '';
        $filename = isset( $file['name'] ) ? $file['name'] : '';

        if ( empty( $tmp_name ) or ! is_uploaded_file( $tmp_name ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $filename = $this->canonicalize( $filename, array( 'strto' => 'as-is' ) );
        $filename = $this->anti_script_file_name( $filename );
        $new_file = path_join( $rand_dir, $filename );

        if ( move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name, $new_file ) ) {
            // Make sure the uploaded file is only readable for the owner process
            chmod( $new_file, 0400 );

            $url = "{$this->get_upload_url()}" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "{$this->rand}" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "{$filename}";
            if ( $return_url ) {
                return $url;
            }

            return $new_file;
        }

        return;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves uploads directory information.
     *
     * @param string|bool $type Optional. Type of output. Default false.
     * @return array|string Information about the upload directory.
     */
    public function upload_dir( $type = false ) {
        $uploads = wp_get_upload_dir();

        $uploads = apply_filters( "{$this->project_name}_upload_dir", array(
            'dir' => $uploads['basedir'],
            'url' => $uploads['baseurl'],
        ) );

        if ( 'dir' == $type ) {
            return $uploads['dir'];
        }
        if ( 'url' == $type ) {
            return $uploads['url'];
        }

        return $uploads;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a child directory with a randomly generated name.
     *
     * @param string $dir The parent directory path.
     * @return string The child directory path if created, otherwise the parent.
     */
    public function maybe_add_random_dir( $dir ) {
        do {
            $rand_max   = mt_getrandmax();
            $this->rand = zeroise( mt_rand( 0, $rand_max ), strlen( $rand_max ) );
            $dir_new    = path_join( $dir, $this->rand );
        } while ( file_exists( $dir_new ) );

        if ( wp_mkdir_p( $dir_new ) ) {
            return $dir_new;
        }

        return $dir;
    }

    /**
     * Cleans up files in the temporary directory for uploaded files.
     *
     * @param int $seconds Files older than this are removed. Default 60.
     * @param int $max Maximum number of files to be removed in a function call.
     *                 Default 100.
     */
    public function cleanup_upload_files() {

        if ( is_admin()
            or 'GET' != $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
            or is_robots()
            or is_feed()
            or is_trackback() ) {
            return;
        }

        $dir = trailingslashit( $this->get_upload_dir() );

        if ( ! is_dir( $dir )
            or ! is_readable( $dir )
            or ! wp_is_writable( $dir ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $seconds = absint( $this->seconds );
        $max     = absint( $this->max );
        $count   = 0;

        if ( $handle = opendir( $dir ) ) {
            while ( false !== ( $file = readdir( $handle ) ) ) {
                if ( '.' == $file
                    or '..' == $file
                    or '.htaccess' == $file ) {
                    continue;
                }

                $mtime = @filemtime( path_join( $dir, $file ) );

                if ( $mtime and time() < $mtime + $seconds ) { // less than $seconds old
                    continue;
                }

                $this->project_rmdir_p( path_join( $dir, $file ) );
                $count += 1;

                if ( $max <= $count ) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            closedir( $handle );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes directory recursively.
     *
     * @param string $dir Directory path.
     * @return bool True on success, false on failure.
     */
    public function project_rmdir_p( $dir ) {
        if ( is_file( $dir ) ) {
            $file = $dir;

            if ( @unlink( $file ) ) {
                return true;
            }

            $stat = stat( $file );

            if ( @chmod( $file, $stat['mode'] | 0200 ) ) { // add write for owner
                if ( @unlink( $file ) ) {
                    return true;
                }

                @chmod( $file, $stat['mode'] );
            }

            return false;
        }

        if ( ! is_dir( $dir ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        if ( $handle = opendir( $dir ) ) {
            while ( false !== ( $file = readdir( $handle ) ) ) {
                if ( $file == "."
                    or $file == ".." ) {
                    continue;
                }

                $this->project_rmdir_p( path_join( $dir, $file ) );
            }

            closedir( $handle );
        }

        if ( false !== ( $files = scandir( $dir ) )
            and ! array_diff( $files, array( '.', '..' ) ) ) {
            return rmdir( $dir );
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the directory path for uploaded files.
     *
     * @return string Directory path.
     */
    public function get_upload_dir() {
        $dir = path_join( $this->upload_dir( 'dir' ), $this->dir_name );
        wp_mkdir_p( $dir );

        return $dir;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the directory url for uploaded files.
     *
     * @return string Directory path.
     */
    public function get_upload_url() {
        $url = path_join( $this->upload_dir( 'url' ), $this->dir_name );
        wp_mkdir_p( $url );

        return $url;
    }

    /**
     * Canonicalizes text.
     *
     * @param string $text Input text.
     * @param string|array|object $args Options.
     * @return string Canonicalized text.
     */
    public function canonicalize( $text, $args = '' ) {
        // for back-compat
        if ( is_string( $args ) and '' !== $args
            and false === strpos( $args, '=' ) ) {
            $args = array(
                'strto' => $args,
            );
        }

        $args = wp_parse_args( $args, array(
            'strto'            => 'lower',
            'strip_separators' => false,
        ) );

        static $charset = null;

        if ( ! isset( $charset ) ) {
            $charset = get_option( 'blog_charset' );

            $is_utf8 = in_array(
                $charset,
                array( 'utf8', 'utf-8', 'UTF8', 'UTF-8' )
            );

            if ( $is_utf8 ) {
                $charset = 'UTF-8';
            }
        }

        $text = html_entity_decode( $text, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, $charset );

        if ( function_exists( 'mb_convert_kana' ) ) {
            $text = mb_convert_kana( $text, 'asKV', $charset );
        }

        if ( $args['strip_separators'] ) {
            $text = preg_replace( '/[\r\n\t ]+/', '', $text );
        } else {
            $text = preg_replace( '/[\r\n\t ]+/', ' ', $text );
        }

        if ( 'lower' == $args['strto'] ) {
            if ( function_exists( 'mb_strtolower' ) ) {
                $text = mb_strtolower( $text, $charset );
            } else {
                $text = strtolower( $text );
            }
        } elseif ( 'upper' == $args['strto'] ) {
            if ( function_exists( 'mb_strtoupper' ) ) {
                $text = mb_strtoupper( $text, $charset );
            } else {
                $text = strtoupper( $text );
            }
        }

        $text = trim( $text );

        return $text;
    }

    /**
     * Converts a file name to one that is not executable as a script.
     *
     * @param string $filename File name.
     * @return string Converted file name.
     */
    public function anti_script_file_name( $filename ) {
        $filename = wp_basename( $filename );

        $filename = preg_replace( '/[\r\n\t -]+/', '-', $filename );
        $filename = preg_replace( '/[\pC\pZ]+/iu', '', $filename );

        $parts = explode( '.', $filename );

        if ( count( $parts ) < 2 ) {
            return $filename;
        }

        $script_pattern = '/^(php|phtml|pl|py|rb|cgi|asp|aspx)\d?$/i';

        $filename  = array_shift( $parts );
        $extension = array_pop( $parts );

        foreach ( (array) $parts as $part ) {
            if ( preg_match( $script_pattern, $part ) ) {
                $filename .= '.' . $part . '_';
            } else {
                $filename .= '.' . $part;
            }
        }

        if ( preg_match( $script_pattern, $extension ) ) {
            $filename .= '.' . $extension . '_.txt';
        } else {
            $filename .= '.' . $extension;
        }

        return $filename;
    }
}
```

To upload the file in temp folder you have to instantiate the Temporary_File_Manager Class.

```
<?php
use HeyMehedi\Temporary_File_Manager;

include_once 'temporary-file-manager.php';

$temp_file_manager = new Temporary_File_Manager( array() );

$returned_file_dir = $temp_file_manager->upload_files( true );

echo '<img src="' . $returned_file_dir[0] . '"/>';
```

For reference you can check this repo: https://github.com/HeyMehedi/Temporary-File-Manager

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/256317)

Comment: Thanks, @vancoder, the answer is updated. I will keep this in mind for future answers.